# CreateView Model Objects to a template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

So I am trying to pass a list of objects into my template. I want my profile.html to reflect the information in the model. I found some documentation on ListView but nothing on CreateView. 
The only thing that is passing through to the template is {{ user.username }}. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

profile.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}User Profile{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<p>User: {{ user.username }} logged in.</p>
<p><a href="{% url 'homepage' %}">homepage</a></p>
<p><a href="{% url 'logout' %}">logout</a></p>
{% else %}
<a href="{% url 'login' %}">login</a> |
<a href="{% url 'signup' %}">signup</a>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

models.py

```
class Volunteer(CustomUser):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    about_me = models.TextField(default='')    

    class Meta:
         db_table = "volunteer"
```

forms.py

```
class VolunteerSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):

class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
    model = Volunteer
    fields = ("username", "email", "first_name", "last_name",)
@transaction.atomic
def save(self):
    user = super(VolunteerSignUpForm, self).save(commit=False)
    user.is_volunteer = True
    user.save()
    return user
```

views.py

```
class VolunteerSignUp(CreateView):
form_class = VolunteerSignUpForm
success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
template_name = 'volunteer_signup.html'
#added code from answer
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(VolunteerSignUp, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['profile_list'] = Volunteer.objects.all()
    return context
```

profile.html Here are some things iv tried to get the info across that didn't work.

```
<ul>
    {% for volunteer in object_list %}
    <li>{{ volunteer.about_me }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

<ul>
    {% for volunteer in profile_list %}
    <li>{{ volunteer.about_me }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

{% if profile_list %}

{% else %}
  <p>There is no info.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: what information do you want to be reflected in template?

Comment: I'd love to add each field into a separate paragraph. I tried iterating it with  {% if profile_list %} which didn't work, so I tried adding it with 
{% for volunteer in object_list %}
 <li>{{ volunteer.about_me }}</li>
{% endfor %}
and that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use get_context_data() method in your class.

```
class VolunteerSignUp(CreateView):
    form_class = VolunteerSignUpForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'volunteer_signup.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(VolunteerSignUp, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        data['profile_list'] = 'your queryset goes here'
        return data
```

Comment: What should my HTML template be to pass the info through? 
    <ul>
        {% for volunteer in profile_list%}
            {{ volunteer.about_me }}
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
isnt working as I had thought it would.

Comment: replace this     
context = super(VolunteerListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)  with
context = super(VolunteerSignUp, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)